# oAuth Server to Server grant flow

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have implemented an OAuth 2.0 server-to-server authentication for a web application I am developing.

Both services are internal to my company, so I send a request from server A to server B containing the username, password, client_id and client_secret then I receive an access_token in response.

After that, I can send a second request from A to B containing the access_token in the header to pull some data.

The data retrieved from server B to server A is finally passed to the view in server A and shown to the end-user.
Therefore I never ask for any inputs to the end-user, because I am using the above "service account" to pull the data that I need. The end-users do not even know anything about such a connection in the background.

Having that said, I am now getting mad to explain to my colleagues that this is a secure approach.
I was wondering if somebody has any official documentation or best practices to share with me that can help to justify to the IT vertical that this approach is correct. I have been told that the basic auth method is not allowed in the company, but this is not really basic auth, isn't it?!
I cannot even find the right name for this, somebody refers to this method as password grant flow, somebody else as two-legged OAuth. The fact is, in my case all interaction happens server-server without any inputs needed from the end users.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**RESOURCE OWNER PASSWORD GRANT**

You are using this flow between Server A and Server B, which is not recommended because OAuth applications should not have access to the the end user's password. It is more standard to use the [Client Credentials Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/client-credentials-flow) for Server to Server calls.

**OAUTH TOKEN ISSUER**

Another aspect that is non standard is that Server B should not issue its own tokens. It is more standard to use an off the shelf Authorization Server (AS) to deal with OAuth messages and token issuing. The AS is the only party that sees credentials - your UIs and APIs only ever use tokens, which have a short expiry compared to credentials.